# Dynamic Grouping Crystal Reports 9

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that has a report parameter that can be a value between 1 and 100.
If the value is less than 50, I need to group by CustomerID.  If the value is greater than 50, I need to group by OrderID.

I've been searching the web on how to do this and I've come across several links that says this can be done via a formula.  So inside the formula I have:

```
if {ReportParameter} < 50 then
    {TableName.CustomerID}
else
    {TableName.OrderID}
```

I created a group manually that correctly sifts through the data, but when I drag the formula into a grouped category, it's not working for me.

Is there an additional step I'm missing?

Comment: A couple questions: When you say that you "Created a group manually" do you mean you just inserted groups as {TableName.CustomerID} and {TableName.OrderID}? And when you try to group by this formula, what exactly do you mean when you say "it's not working"?

Comment: Yes, I inserted groups (Insert > Group) just to see if I could group data successfully and that worked.  So I removed the label out of the group section and tried putting a formula there instead which is not working.

Comment: I don't see any problem using that formula to group on. It's not working in that the records aren't getting grouped at all? What displays as the Group Name when you do this?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I didn't want the CustomerID to show, I wanted the Customer Name to display instead when I was inserting the group the first time.

so I right-clicked on the gray area to the left of the report and selected "Change Group" which launched the Change Group Options and went to the Options tab to customize the Group Name Field

Comment: It's not working in that the records aren't getting grouped the way they should.

Comment: I would check the Group Expert that you are, in fact, grouping on the formula you think you are as PowerUser suggests and that there is no custom name defined. When you run the report something must display for the Group Name in the Group Header... whether it is just a null or an actual value, it should give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is how I ended up doing this:

I defined the formula, but I didn't link the group to the formula.  So I went back to the Group Header > Change Group > Change Group Options > Options Tab

and pointed to the name of my formula and it worked.

I thought that by adding the formula to the Group Header, CR would automatically associate my formula with the Group Header.  DOH!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for me to tackle this one...

1. If I understand your follow-up comments correctly, all you did was change the display name of the group, you didn't actually change the grouping. I tried this myself just to make sure and that's what it looks like to me.
2. <strike>Second, (someone correct me if I'm wrong), *you cannot group on a formula*. I also tried this in CR2010 and couldn't do it.</strike>
   (**Edit** scratch that. Ryan is right. I am wrong)
3. I recommend using **Reports**->**Group Expert** to see what is grouped where.  By default, it should also be on your toolbar.

I can think of 2 ways of setting up your report that would make this issue null and void:

1. Make 2 separate reports, 1 for each view.  Set the selection criteria appropriately

OR

1. Make 1 Master report.  Set up your group, page, and report headers & footers in here.  Before the data gets into Crystal, create a field to act as your 'index' (perhaps with the formula you listed) and group on that.
2. Create 2 details subsections. If you want to change the label of your groups, just drag & drop a formula field onto your group header.
3. Suppress the first subsection if {ReportParameter} < 50.  Create a subreport in there and group that subreport by {OrderID}.
4. Suppress the second subsection if {ReportParameter} > 50.  Create a subreport in there and group that subreport by {CustomerID}.

Comment: I very frequently group on formulas. Most of my reports include some sort of flexible grouping that allows the user to specify exactly what coson is trying to accomplish... that is, based on a parameter group by this field, otherwise group by this other field. I've done this in both XI and 2008 with no problems.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my answer accordingly.  I don't know why I thought that.

Comment: For my own knowledge, can you define "flexible group"? Not familiar with that term.

Comment: By "flexible group" I just mean a parameterized group - one that can take on a number of possible fields and/or calculated values depending on a report run instance. Sorry, maybe that's not commonly used terminology, but I don't know what else to call it :)